# How twisted.python.failure.Failure exceptions.IOError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor show up?

Tags: python, scrapy, phantomjs, twisted

```
def start_requests(self):
    reqs = []
    dr = webdriver.PhantomJS(self.get_path())
    dr.get('http://www.catcmipc.org.cn/isoc/toNewsList?types=%E9%87%8D%E7%82%B9%E5%85%B3%E6%B3%A8&ids=21')
    try:
        wait = WebDriverWait(dr, 20)
        element = wait.until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable(
                (By.CLASS_NAME, 'newslist_content_title')))
    except:
        dr.quit()
    origin_url = dr.current_url
    valid_next = True
    while valid_next:
        origin_url = origin_url.replace('List', "View")
        for elem in dr.find_elements_by_class_name(
                'newslist_content_title'):
            page_id = elem.get_attribute('onclick')
            idx = page_id.index('(')
            url = origin_url[:-2] + page_id[idx + 1:-1]
            reqs.append(
                scrapy.Request(
                    url,
                    callback=self.parse,
                    dont_filter=True))
        if dr.find_elements_by_xpath(
                '//li[@class="pgNext"]')[-2].text == '下一页'.decode('utf-8'):
            dr.find_elements_by_xpath('//li[@class="pgNext"]')[-2].click()
            valid_next = True
            try:
                wait = WebDriverWait(dr, 20)
                element = wait.until(
                    EC.element_to_be_clickable(
                        (By.CLASS_NAME, 'newslist_content_title')))
            except:
                dr.quit()
        else:
            valid_next = False
    return reqs

def parse(self, response):
    self.logger.info('visit {}'.format(response.url[-4:]))
    dr = webdriver.PhantomJS(self.get_path())
    try:
        dr.get(response.url)
        try:
            wait = WebDriverWait(dr, 20)
            element = wait.until(
                EC.visibility_of_element_located(
                    (By.CLASS_NAME, 'newscontent_content')))
        except:
            dr.quit()
        item = ZhongyaochanyeItem()
        item['url'] = response.url
        item['text'] = dr.find_element_by_xpath(
            '//div[@class="newslist_content"]').text
        dr.quit()
        if item['text']:
            yield item
        else:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=response.url, callback=self.parse, dont_filter=True)
    except:
        self.logger.error('rerererevisit {}'.format(response.url[-4:]))
        yield scrapy.Request(url=response.url, callback=self.parse, dont_filter=True)
```

This is my code in scrapy ,the total requests are 155 ,but when I run the code , it sometimes get wrong

> [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Error downloading http://www.catcmipc.org.cn/isoc/toNewsView?types=%E9%87%8D%E7%82%B9%E5%85%B3%E6%B3%A8&ids=1415>:
>   []

Above is the error information , I'm new in scrapy, plz tell me what lead to the problem?Thank you

Comment: See http://sscce.org/